# build android project without gradle (shell script, makefile etc)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

As the title says - I'm sick of everything changing under my legs and having to spend pointless hours trying to make the project compile again when something updates (despite still having the same explicit versions of everything defined). And no, to clarify, I DO NOT WANT Gradle - I want a completely, 100%, Gradle-free experience (or any other online "smart" build system - I'll download the libraries myself, thank you). I need reproduceability, not ease of use. I need a deterministic workflow without online dependencies. If it compiles once, it has to compile again. Gradle, in my limited experience, doesn't guarantee this - I don't care who's the culprit, whether Gradle itself or the Android plugins or whatever.

Comment: Why you want and What you want...please be specific..

Comment: Ok, sorry - I want to build Android projects without using Gradle at all, as I'm having problems with it - what compiled ok now fails with cryptic error messages referring me to logs that I'm unable to find. Only thing that changed is the Android Studio version. I don't want to spend hours making it work every time something changes somewhere. And, also, when I project project x in Android Studio, for some reason it compiles project y, which has ABSOLUTELY NO CONNECTION to project x (no shar deps, nthng in cmn), ending up in an infinite loop (never finishes). Project x fails, no reason given.

Comment: RE: duplicate - I agree, that question has sufficient answers for me, sorry for spamming...